# what is the best way to split the string

Tags: php

I have this string set

```
Host: example.com, IP address: 37.0.122.151, SBL: SBL196170, status: unknown, level: 4, Malware: Citadel, AS: 198310, country: RU
```

I would like to have each data in this format.

```
$host = "example.com";
$ip = "37.0.122.151";
$SBL = "SBL196170";
$status = unknown;
$level = "4";
$malware = "Citadel";
$as = "1098310";
$country = "RU";
```

What is the best way to get that string? Should I split by `","` first and `":"` later or there is a solution with one split?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be a good use case for regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
$input = "Host: example.com, IP address: 37.0.122.151, SBL: SBL196170, status: unknown, level: 4, Malware: Citadel, AS: 198310, country: RU";
preg_match_all('/(\w+): ([\w.]+)/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Host: example.com
            [1] => address: 37.0.122.151
            [2] => SBL: SBL196170
            [3] => status: unknown
            [4] => level: 4
            [5] => Malware: Citadel
            [6] => AS: 198310
            [7] => country: RU
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Host
            [1] => address
            [2] => SBL
            [3] => status
            [4] => level
            [5] => Malware
            [6] => AS
            [7] => country
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => example.com
            [1] => 37.0.122.151
            [2] => SBL196170
            [3] => unknown
            [4] => 4
            [5] => Citadel
            [6] => 198310
            [7] => RU
        )

)
```

Then:

```
$mydata = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($mydata);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [Host] => example.com
    [address] => 37.0.122.151
    [SBL] => SBL196170
    [status] => unknown
    [level] => 4
    [Malware] => Citadel
    [AS] => 198310
    [country] => RU
)
```

Comment: I think regular expression so much for that simple parse, and in this case you are using 4 arrays. The "problem" could be if a key or value can have a `,` or `:` inside a espace sequence like `key: "v,alue"`

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento there are no quoted strings indicated in the input format, and if we have to worry about "what happens if someone feeds bad input into my program" then no one will ever get anything done. Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Comment: I agree with you in the first paragraph. But about the other, no way, you should always check for valid input or you are going to give exploits to not good intentioned users.

Comment: Like the approach, and I don't think the concern raised by Diego is very serious: if indeed the keys or values could have junk like that in them, there's really little possibility of parsing the string using **any** approach. If a string won't conform to any type of rule or pattern, you really can't expect to be able to reliably use it like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple explode on the string, and then for each element populate an array with the key/value information:

```
$string = 'Host: ...';
$raw_array = explode(',', $string);
$final_array = array();
foreach($raw_array as $item) {
    $item_array = explode(':', trim($item));
    $key = trim($item_array[0]);
    $value = trim($item_array[1]);
    $final_array[$key] = $value;
}
var_dump($final_array);
```

Note that this is not using individual variable like asked in your question, but rather populating a single array with key value based on the keys of the string.  This is a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex replacement to turn it into a query string-esq string, then use `parse_str` to turn it into an associative array. No loops, two lines!

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/:/', '/, /'), array('=','&'), $string);
parse_str($string, $output);

var_dump($output);
/*
array(8) { ["Host"]=> string(8) " xxx.com" ["IP_address"]=> string(13) " 37.0.122.151" ["SBL"]=> string(10) " SBL196170" ["status"]=> string(8) " unknown" ["level"]=> string(2) " 4" ["Malware"]=> string(8) " Citadel" ["AS"]=> string(7) " 198310" ["country"]=> string(3) " RU" } 
*/
```

Try it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/5gwWyC

**Documentation**

- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `parse_str` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a bit of functional programming into the mix, you get:

```
$string = 'Host: xxx.com, IP address: 37.0.122.151, SBL: SBL196170, status: unknown, level: 4, Malware: Citadel, AS: 198310, country: RU';
$result = array_reduce(explode(',', $string), function($result, $item) {
    $pair = explode(':', $item);
    $result[trim($pair[0])] = trim($pair[1]);
    return $result;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple and handy function I use all the time for things like this.

```
<?php

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$src = "Host: xxx.com, IP address: 37.0.122.151, SBL: SBL196170, status: unknown, level: 4, Malware: Citadel, AS: 198310, country: RU";

//add a character to src to help identify the last field
$src = $src.",";

$host = get_string_between($src, "Host: ", ","); //this is grabbing any text between "Host: " and ","
$ip = get_string_between($src, "IP address: ", ",");
$SBL = get_string_between($src, "SBL: ", ",");
$status = get_string_between($src, "status: ", ",");
$level = get_string_between($src, "level: ", ",");
$malware = get_string_between($src, "Malware: ", ",");
$as = get_string_between($src, "AS: ", ",");
$country = get_string_between($src, "country: ", ",");

?>
```

Happy coding!